# Apache 2 run '*.py' by python 2

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu

I have a error with import some libraries in my python script. This made for python 3 and good work in Terminal. But when I try to start this script by web server (Apache 2) I have error with "cannot import name 'ImageTk'". I think Apache start this script by python 2, but wrote to start by python 3. Could you help me?

Here code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import cgi
import cgitb
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

cgitb.enable()

print('Content-type: application/json\n\n')
res = json.dumps({'age': 0, 'pol': '0', 'status': 0})
print(res)
```

Here error from log:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageTk'

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PIL official website](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), the module is only for Python 2.X.

Also according to [the effbot website](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagetk.htm) on the ImageTk module:

> Note: If you’re using a prebuilt version of PIL, you might need to install additional packages to be able to use the ImageTk module. For example, on Ubuntu, you need both python-imaging and python-imaging-tk.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks! It's pity, but this didn't help me. I renamed '.py' to '.py3' and it's help me.